# Covariance matrix not positive definite

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to solve a portfolio optimization problem with `quadprog` library, but `solve.QP` function returns this:

```
matrix D in quadratic function is not positive definite!
```

But, I'm defining `Dmat` as:

```
Dmat <- cov(diff(as.matrix(na.locf(prices))))
```

How can I turn `Dmat` in a positive definite matrix?

Comment: Maybe adding some regularization could help? Something on the lines of `Dmat <- Dmat + lambda*diag(ncol(Dmat))` where `lambda` is a small constant (a hyperparameter you'd want to tune to find a good value). Although it would add some distortion to your results, it might be an acceptable tradeoff to improve the robustness of the method.

Comment: Try to check the eigenvalues by eigen(Dmat) and if one of them less than zero. There would be some problem with your matrix.Also, sometimes, a high dimension matrix would lead to a huge numerical error if the code is not prepared for such a high dimension problem or just poorly-written.

Comment: Great, I'll try. How would you tune this parameter? Changing lambda in small steps and check when it turns to be positive definite? Or there is a better method?

Comment: @galapagos yes, it has some eigenvalues less than 0. Can it happen because of na.locf?

Comment: Try adding some small values and see what happens to the eigen values, as @galapagos suggested. To properly tune it you'd need some kind of performance metric that you optimize with cross-validation on similar. These type of questions are not really on topic for SO and I think you'd get better help at the [cross-validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) site though so I'll vote for a migration.

Comment: You could try other imputation methods.

Comment: The hint by galapagos is along what is actually done. This article could be a good starting point in the literature: https://repositori.upf.edu/bitstream/handle/10230/560/691.pdf

Comment: Portfolio optimization problems use returns, not price differences so, if your prices object contains asset prices, then you'll need to compute returns using something like:    temp <- as.matrix(na.locf(prices));   Dmat <- cov( diff(temp)/ head(temp,-1)).   Alternatively you could convert prices to log prices and then diff would give you log returns.

Comment: Thanks guys, I already answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help. I discovered the cov.shrink function from corpcor library, and now I'm defining Dmat as:

```
cov.shrink(diff(as.matrix(na.locf(precos_mes))))
```

which works perfectly as a positive definite matrix.